# Djongo not connecting to mlab server

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, djongo

I am using djongo with django2 to connect to mlab mongodb instance.
`settings.py`

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'neon',
        'HOST': 'mongodb://username:password@ds249605.mlab.com:49605/mlab1',
    }
}
```

although I am using this settings, the PyMongo connects to the local instance of mongodb.

`log`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/introspection.py", line 47, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.list_collection_names()
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 856, in list_collection_names
    for result in self.list_collections(session=session, **kwargs)]
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 819, in list_collections
    _cmd, read_pref, session)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1454, in _retryable_read
    read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1253, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 235, in select_server
    address))
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 193, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "/home/rahul/projects/django/neon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: The configuration listed at https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/ shows `host` should be inside `CLIENT`, does it work if you use that?

Comment: Ok, i will try that and let you know.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

## mLab

The host be inside client like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'fitbitt',

        'CLIENT': {
        'host':'mongodb://your_username:your_password@ds363008.mlab.com:63008/fitbitt',
        'username':'your_username',
        'password':'your_password'
        }

    }
}
```